# Pandas values not being updated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to working with Pandas and I'm trying to do a very simple thing with it. Using the `flights.csv` file I'm defining a new column which defines a new column with `underperforming` if the number of passengers is below average, the value is `1`. My problem is that it might be something wrong with the logic since it's not updating the values. Here is an example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('flights.csv')
 
passengers_mean = df['passengers'].mean()
df['underperforming'] = 0

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['passengers'] < passengers_mean):
        row['underperforming'] = 1


print(df)
print(passengers_mean)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases.

[iterrows docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

What you can do instead is:

```
df["underperforming"] = (df.passengers < x.passengers.mean()).astype('int')
```

Comment: So it evaluates if it's True or False and represents as interger. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not
> guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
> iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
> effect.

Kindly use vectorized operations like [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)